# Bulleted list with indentation in Facebook comments?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to have a bulleted list in a Facebook comment, with multiple levels of indentation:

- Something

  - More about it
- Something else

I don't care whether it uses actual bullets, or hyphens, or anything else as long as it can convey that structure.

However, Facebook insists on stripping out my leading whitespace, so the best I can do is

```
- Something
- More about it
- Something else
```

This gets very confusing with a long, complex list. Is it possible to properly indent my list in a Facebook comment?

Answer (score 4):

You can use ideographic spaces (　) to preserve indentations in Facebook.

Here's a Facebook comment in progress:

[image: editing a Facebook comment with indentations]

Here's what it looks like after pressing Enter to submit it:

[image: a Facebook comment with indentations]

For the 2nd line, ("i. Indented"), I began the line by inserting an Ideographic Space with the help of the Character Viewer:

[image: Mac OS X character viewer, ideographic space (and a leading backspace character, which I've learned is not needed)]

The third and fourth lines ("a. Nested" and "• And so forth.") have two and three ideographic spaces, respectively.

Facebook's leading-space-stripping algorithm does not seem to expect the somewhat exotic ideographic space, so it doesn't strip it out. In time, Facebook may figure this one out, but for now, it works fine.

Comment: I didn't need any backspace, ideographic spaces by themselves are preserved at the beginning of lines.

Answer (score 2):

To confirm the answer above, I was able to indent text in a Facebook posting using ONLY the Ideographic Space. To find the Ideographic Space, open the Keyboard Preferences and then check the box to show the keyboard menu and Character Viewer icon in the menu bar. Bring up the Character Viewer. Under the tool menu button (gear symbol) scroll down and add Unicode to the options list. Select Unicode from the list on the left and then scroll down to the 3000 line. The Ideagraphic Space is the first character.

Comment: Worked for me on Windoze